# How to get JSON value from RestTemplate

Tags: java, json, resttemplate

I would like to retrieve the value of a JSON file from a RestTemplate request. Unfortunately, I do not know how to proceed. I am using the following method:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
final String url = "http://localhost:3333/command/core/get-csrf-token";

public String getToken() {
    String token = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
    System.out.println(token);
    return token;
```

I get a String as output `{"token":"myToken"}`

Is it possible to retrieve directly the value of the JSON?

Comment: You can use an `ObjectMapper` to map it to a Java object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse the JSON with a library (e.g. Jackson) and grab the `token` field.

```
String json = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
return mapper.readTree(json).get("token").asText();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say `String.class`, you're asking RestTemplate to give you the result as a String. Instead, you can do either of these:

```
class TokenHolder {
    String token;
}

TokenHolder holder = restTemplate.getForObject(url, TokenHolder.class);
holder.getToken();
```

or

```
// this is necessary because of generic type erasure
private static final ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, String>> MAP_TYPE = 
     new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {};

Map<String, String> map = restTemplate.getForObject(url, MAP);
map.get("token");
```

The "strong type" `TokenHolder` is generally preferable. Lombok's `@Value` and the brand-new Java Record feature can help create such classes with little boilerplate.